# Most clever way to parse a Facebook OAuth 2 access token string

Tags: regex

It's a bit late, but I'm disappointed in myself for not coming up with something more elegant. Anyone have a better way to do this...

When you pass an OAuth code to Facebook, it response with a query string containing `access_token` and `expires` values.

```
access_token=121843224510409|2.V_ei_d_rbJt5iS9Jfjk8_A__.3600.1273741200-569255561|TxQrqFKhiXm40VXVE1OBUtZc3Ks.&expires=4554
```

Although if you request permission for offline access, there's no `expires` and the string looks like this:

```
access_token=121843224510409|2.V_ei_d_rbJt5iS9Jfjk8_A__.3600.1273741200-569255561|TxQrqFKhiXm40VXVE1OBUtZc3Ks.
```

I attempted to write a regex that would suffice for either condition. No dice. So I ended up with some really ugly Ruby:

```
s = s.split("=")
@oauth = {}
if s.length == 3
  @oauth[:access_token] = s[1][0, s[1].length - 8]
  @oauth[:expires] = s[2]
else
  @oauth[:access_token] = s[1]
end
```

I know there must be a better way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is strict, then you use this regex:

```
access_token=([^&]+)(?:&expires=(.*))?
```

Then `access_token` value is in `\1`, and `expires`, if there's any, will be in `\2`.

Comment: On the strictness, yep, this works as long as a "&" is never part of the access token. Not sure if that's a safe assumption. Couldn't find anything in the spec to validate.

Answer (score 4):

Split on the `&` symbol first, and then split each of the results on `=`? That's the method that can cope with the order changing, since it parses each key-value pair individually.

Alternatively, a regex that should work would be...

```
/access_token=(.*?)(?:&expires=(.*))/
```

Comment: That's the one I was toying around with. It fails when "&expires=" is not in the string.

Comment: Um, then you're poorly implementing it - you shouldn't be explicitly referencing indices, but instead looking at the key that comes out of the first part of each `=` split. As in, `a = s.split("&")`, then for each value in `a`, `p = a.split("=")`, and then check what `p[0]` is equal to for the key name first, then assign `p[1]` to the proper variable based on the key. It shouldn't matter what is in your string then. That's the whole advantage of using `split` in the first place.

Comment: Also, your code in the OP is splitting on `=` only, not `&` first.

Comment: Sorry, failed to read your `split` directive. If you edit your answer (anything), I'll be able to vote it back up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Query string parsing usually involves these steps:

1. If it is a complete URL, take the part after the first `?`
2. split the rest on `&`
3. for each of the resulting `name=value` pairs, split them on `=`
4. URL-decode to the `value` *and* the `name` (!)
5. stuff the result into a data structure of your liking

Using regex is possible, but makes invalid assumptions about the state of URL-encoding the string is in and fails if the order of the query string changes, which is perfectly allowed and therefore cannot be ruled out. Better to encapsulate the above in a little parsing function or use one of the existing URL-handling libraries of your platform.